# Coded UI Testing: Textbox value always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, assert, coded-ui-tests

I'm new to coded UI testing, can someone help me on how to retrieve a textbox value as I keep on getting null value. I added an assertion to my method which validates the value of a textbox, however if keeps on failing since the actual data is always null. Below is my sample code. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is my test method in the CodeUItest class

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TBParameterTest()
    {
        this.UIMap.ValidateTBValue();            
    }


 public void ValidateTBValue()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinEdit uIItemEdit = this.UIContigoWindow.UIItemCell.UIItemEdit;


        #endregion

        // Verify that the 'Text' property of text box equals '1200'
        Assert.AreEqual(this.ValidateTBValueExpectedValues.UIItemEditText, uIItemEdit.Text, "Not equal to previous value when parameter is not yet modified");
    }
```

the uIItemEdit.Text is always null even if the value in the webpage is equal to 1200.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing a .DrawHighlight() on the uIItemEdit to verify that you're dealing with the correct control? Can we see the code for UIItemEdit?

Comment: @NickRaverty I tried to put .DrawHiglight and its pointing to a wrong location. I'm also wondering why does my control not have automationId property. It seems that the uiItemEdit control refers to all textbox in my page, thus those textboxes does not have unique name so I can't search it.

Comment: The fact that it's pointing at the wrong control is why you're not getting the right value - It's pulling the null value from the first control on the page, you'll need to set up the search properties on the control that you actually want to deal with. Good luck!

Comment: @jbaDaniel, did Nick's suggestion work?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in two different ways:

1. The better options is to adjust the search properties to search for some unique identifier (Name, class...).
2. The second option, in case a unique identifier cannot be found or added by the Developers, is using the `FindMatchingControls()` that every `UITestControl` has. This will give you all the controls, in your case all the `WinEdit` controls that match the `SearchProperties`. On this collection of controls you can run Link queries to find the desired control, or run something like:

```
var controls= myControl.FindMatchingControls()l

foreach (var control in controls) 
{ 
    control.DrawHighlight();
}
```

This will enable you to locate the desired control. From this point on you could call it directly and get it's text value:

```
var textValue = controls[index].Text;
```

and use this value for your assertion.